# How to connect a parent and a child node using line shapes in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, scenekit

I'm making Human Skeleton 3D graphics using `SceneKit`. Right now I have a node parent-child hierarchy for the human arm like this:

[image: Arm Nodes]

In this example I have 3 joint nodes to create an arm. It consists of shoulder, elbow, and hand nodes. The shoulder is the root parent node, the elbow is a child of the shoulder, and the hand is a child of the elbow. I want to create a line connecting these nodes using `SCNCylinder`. Originally I added all of the nodes into the scene's `rootNode` and I have no problem with it. But because I'm implementing Inverse Kinematics using `SCNIKConstraint` I created a parent-child relationship for each node like this. Apparently, the method I used earlier to create the line between each node doesn't work as expected anymore. Here's the original method I used:

```
private func createLineBetweenNodes(type: SkeletonType) -> SCNNode? {
        // Getting the joint positions from a json data. The data was get from motion capture
        guard
            let originKeypointVector = currentKeypoint.getKeypoint(type: type.originKeypoint)?.getConvertedPosition(relativeTo: CGFloat(studioSize)),
            let destinationKeypointVector = currentKeypoint.getKeypoint(type: type.destinationKeypoint)?.getConvertedPosition(relativeTo: CGFloat(studioSize))
        else { return nil }
        
        // I'm guessing I have to change the formula to create the vector, distance, and midPosition? But this is the original formula that I use
        let vector = SCNVector3Make(originKeypointVector.x - destinationKeypointVector.x,
                                    originKeypointVector.y - destinationKeypointVector.y,
                                    originKeypointVector.z - destinationKeypointVector.z)
        let distance = sqrt(vector.x * vector.x + vector.y * vector.y + vector.z * vector.z)
        let midPosition = SCNVector3Make((originKeypointVector.x + destinationKeypointVector.x) / 2,
                                         (originKeypointVector.y + destinationKeypointVector.y) / 2,
                                         (originKeypointVector.z + destinationKeypointVector.z) / 2)
        
        let line = SCNCylinder()
        line.radius = CGFloat(lineRadius)
        line.height = CGFloat(distance)
        line.radialSegmentCount = 5
        
        let lineNode = SCNNode(geometry: line)
        lineNode.position = midPosition
        lineNode.look(at: destinationKeypointVector,
                      up: scene!.rootNode.worldUp,
                      localFront: lineNode.worldUp)
        
        return lineNode
    }
```

My question is how do I change the formula code to create the `vector`, `distance`, and `midPosition` to achieve this? Because I'm guessing these are the 3 key parts that have to change. If you need more information regarding this please let me know.

**NOTE:** The elbow node's position is changed whenever I change the `targetPosition` of the IK constraint that I made. The chain root node for the constraint is the shoulder node, and I set the constraint to the hand node. So I didn't change the elbow's node position manually.